# Excel UDF not working on another computer

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I have searched the internet and Stack Overflow, but couldn't find an answer to my problem.

I defined a UDF in Excel, it's saved in a module in an .xlam Add-In. The UDF works perfectly fine on my computer. Now I'm trying to use the workbook which uses the UDF on another computer (in a different language) with the same .xlam Add-In active. However Excel suddenly references the entire path to the add-in file as an "absolute path" instead of only showing the function name itself. The result is a #NAME? error because Excel doesn't find the UDF.

[How I have written the VBA Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NfDW.png)

[How it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHX8J.png)

[How it looks on another computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3XGb.png)

Has anyone had this issue and found a solution for it? I could try to find a workaround without the UDF function but I'd prefer that it works this way. Another time the situation might be more complex ...

Comment: Please add the code to the post as text so that we can test it and edit it.

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24925424/how-to-keep-reference-to-add-in-udf-when-workbook-moved-to-different-folder-than). The answer is quite convoluted unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you @ChristoferWeber, that is useful information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your UDF is the location of the `.xlam` file.  You can find information on dealing with that by following the link in the comments above provided by Christofer Weber.

Having said that, I think it may be more beneficial for you to use the built-in formula that excel has for this which is `EOMONTH()`

`EOMONTH()` can be used to return both the last day of a month and the first day of a month (by finding the last day of the previous month and adding 1)

You can find more information on `EOMONTH()` here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/eomonth-function-7314ffa1-2bc9-4005-9d66-f49db127d628

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion! I didn't know about EOMONTH which does indeed yield the result I'm looking for. It doesn't solve the Add-in issue though, for which the answer of Christofer Weber did point me in the right direction for other UDF functions that don't have a built-in Excel version (that I know of :))