# Prevent Excel from saving UDF path to formula cells

Tags: excel, hyperlink, path, add-in, udf

I'm using a custom Add-in which adds functions to Excel, like UDF1(param1, param2).

> (1) example call in cell:
> =UDF1(param1, param2)

When saving workbook1, which implements UDF(), Excel silently adds the path to the Add-in to each call of UDF(). This can be seen when uninstalling the Add-in and reopening workbook1.

> Excel asks to update external references, I click "don't update".
>
> (2) new cell content: ='\...\user\Desktop\Addin1'!UDF1(param1, param2)

**How to prevent Excel from saving the path to the Add-in when saving the workbook?**

I would like the new cell content (2) to match the original content (1).

(This is particularly annoying when different people are using the same Add-in, respectively installed in a different location of their computers, as it requires deleting the '\......!' path from each cell each time the workbook is opened by another user.)

Edit: [Remove AddIn path from UDF in Excel formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414719/remove-addin-path-from-udf-in-excel-formula) and http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/FixLinks2UDF.asp is not what I'm looking for, as the suggested "solutions" are workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

You researched very well the issue*, and you found the answer that you did not like: what you want to do is not possible.

That is the way Excel refers to UDFs (similarly, when you refer to cells in open vs. not-open workbooks).

You need a workaround, either of those proposed in the links you provide, or perhaps something alternative.

.* It is not the typical case.

Comment: Though its always hard to prove the non-existence of a clean solution, you've confirmed what I expected...

Comment: @user3641140 - Agreed 100%. I have asked questions in the same spirit before.

Comment: BUT - might it be possible that this is an development environment issue? I.e. there might be a way to solve the problem by creating the Add-In in Visual Studio / C#, instead of the Excel-integrated VBA editor? (I know there exist Add-Ins that don't have the problem described above. After all, isn't the purpose of an Add-In to distribute code...?)

Answer (score 0):

As always, there is a way of using user defined functions (UDF) from an addin.
Let us have a function in an excel Addin-File `B.xlam` in a Module we have

```
Public Function Volume(a as Double, b as Double, c as Double)
    Volume = a * b * c
End Function
```

This File has the `Workbook.IsAddin`-Property set to `true` and is stored in the same directory as the consuming Excel Sheet `A.xlsm`. This Excel Sheet has a VBA-Reference to file `B.xlam`. If You then use the Function `Volume` in any Cell of `A.xlsm`, the function is delegated to VBA and VBA also looks, if the Function `Volume` exists in the referenced File `B.xlam`.
[image: References-Example]
So far so good. If in the workbook-view of Excel, refereces are shown (in the data-ribbon), then change the reference from `B.xlam` to the file `A.xlsm` itself. So finally there is no direct Excel-Reference from `A.xlsm` to `B.xlam`. The only reference exists is a VBA-Reference.

Now, if the Addin-File `B.xlam` is loaded before the File `A.xlsm` the reference always refers to the open file. Otherwise VBA looks for the original path and if that does not exist, it looks in the workbook-path.

So this way the UDF may be referenced via VBA and the addin may sit anywhere, if loaded bevore the consuming file or in the same directory of the consuming Excel-file.